# Error:expecting scalar type

Tags: debugging, assembly

I want to finish a program in assembly language,in which I hope it can output all the ASCII characters in [00h, 0FFh] and hexadecimal ASCII in the format of table.But error happens and I try many times but failed.
It shows that **except scalar type** but I do not how to deal with it.
This is the code , error exists in "mov di,col*8":

```
code segment
assume cs:code
main:
    jmp begin
row dw 0
col dw 0
s db 2 dup(0),0Dh,0Ah,'$'
begin:
    mov ax,0B800h
    mov es,ax
    mov di,0
    mov cx,2
    mov bl,00h
next_row:
    mov byte ptr es:[di],bl
    mov byte ptr es:[di+1],04h
    push di
    mov dh,bl
    mov dl,00h
    mov di,0
again:
    push cx
    mov cl,2
    rol dx,cl
    push dx
    and dx, 0000000000001111B
    cmp dx, 10
    jb is_digit
is_alpha:
    sub dl, 10
    add dl, 'A'
    jmp finish_4bits
is_digit:
    add al, '0'
finish_4bits:
    mov s[di], dl
    pop dx
    pop cx
    add di, 1
    sub cx, 1
    jnz again
    pop di
    mov byte ptr es:[di+2],s[0]
    mov byte ptr es:[di+3],02h
    mov byte ptr es:[di+4],s[1]
    mov byte ptr es:[di+5],02h
    push ax
    mov ah,02h
    mov dl,0Dh
    int 21h
    mov ah,02h
    mov dl,0Ah
    int 21h
    pop ax

    add di,110
    add bl,01h
    cmp bl,0FFh
    ja exit
    add row,1
    cmp row,24
    jne next_row
    jmp next_col
next_col:
    mov row,0
    add col,1
    mov di,col*8
    add bl,01h
    jmp next_row
exit:
     mov ah,0
     int 16h;End
code ends 
end main
```

And another question is I do not know how to output the element in s(the hexadecimal ASCII),can you give some advice?

Comment: What does your assembly program have to do with C?

Comment: use `col equ 8` if you want to be able to use `col*8` as an immediate, instead of actually storing `8` in memory.  You don't seem to be using `si` for anything; keep your variable in a register instead of static storage.  Also, instead of incrementing by 1 and multiplying by 8, just increment by 8.  i.e. keep your column value already scaled.

Answer (score 1):

from the syntax I would guess this is MASM/TASM syntax.

In such case `mov di,col*8` is quite bogus...

The `col` is memory "variable" (more accurately `col` is "assembly symbol" having as value the memory address of first byte of the memory defined after that `col` label, which in your case is defined by `dw 0` directive => spawns two bytes with zero value).

Then `mov di,col` is assembled into `mov r16,r/m16` variant of [`mov` instruction](http://x86.renejeschke.de/html/file_module_x86_id_176.html), or in proper Intel syntax to `mov di,[col]` where `col` stands for 16 bit integer value being `OFFSET` part of `col` memory address. The segment part of address is taken by default from `ds`, and if you did set the `ds` properly ahead, the `mov` will reach that memory reserved by `dw`.

`mov di, col*8` is ambiguous, you can assemble that either as `mov di,[col*8]` which would mean to fetch memory from `(OFFSET col)*8` address = NOT what you wanted, or `mov di,[col] * 8` as arithmetic, to multiply the value fetched from memory, and x86 CPU doesn't have such instruction. You need to do the arithmetic on values separately, like:

```
mov    di,[col]
shl    di,3      ; di = di * 8
```

Any "arithmetic-like" operations in `mov` instructions are the memory-address related arithmetic, like `mov eax,[ebx + esi*8]` is valid in 32b mode, and it means the memory address to be fetched is calculated first. There's none arithmetic for value itself built-in in the `mov` instruction of x86 CPU family, except the `movsx/movzx` instructions, which do sign/zero extension to the value. Can't recall any other exception. The "string" family of instructions like `lodsb` adjust the pointer value after fetch, but that's not adjustment of the value itself, only the pointer.

You can exploit the memory address arithmetic CPU module by using `lea` instruction to calculate some arithmetic with values for you, instead of calculating with true memory offsets.

---

In your particular code of course it is more optimal to keep the value in some register, and just do `add xxx,8` to update it, to keep it pre-multiplied all the time, and not storing/reading anything to/from memory. Use memory only as last resort, when you can't fit everything into registers.

---

EDIT: after reading into your source a bit more...

You probably should write your code in many smaller steps, keeping it running+debugging after each one.

At the moment you are mixing direct video ram writes with `int 21h` output routines, which will do no good to you, pick one.

And as you want to display all extended ASCII characters, the direct write is the only choice (as DOS will eat 10, 13 and other control-code values from displaying, and do the special action for them, like moving cursor (new line, tab), beeping, etc.).

And if you want 256 symbols, then 16x16 table makes perfect sense.

So maybe you should have start writing your code by displaying first 16 extended ASCII in single line. Like:

```
code segment
assume cs:code, ds:code
main:
    jmp begin
; reserved for data in future

; top left corner of the table at [0, 4] position
TABLE_LEFT_TOP_OFFSET   equ     (4*80*2)
; the table will be 16x16, each element being 5x1
; total size = 80x16 = (will fit 80x25 text mode screen)
; element 5 chars as:
; symbol, space, first hex digit, second hex digit, space

begin:
    mov     ax,0B800h
    mov     es,ax       ; es = text mode VRAM segment

; display 16 symbols (single row) on proper positions
    mov     di,TABLE_LEFT_TOP_OFFSET ; di = starting VRAM adr
    xor     dl,dl   ; symbol value = 0
    mov     cx,16   ; loop counter
row_loop:
    ; show symbol + space
    mov     al,dl   ; symbol ASCII
    mov     ah,4h   ; colour attribute
    mov     es:[di],ax      ; write symbol
    mov     al,' '
    mov     es:[di+2],ax    ; write space after it
    ; advance loop for next symbol
    inc     dl
    add     di,5*2  ; move 5 chars forward
    dec     cx
    jnz     row_loop

    ; exit back to DOS
    xor     ah,ah   ; ah = 0 - wait for key service
    int     16h
    int     20h     ; terminate to DOS

code ends
end main
```

After you verify this works as expected (shows one line of 16 symbols), you can extend it... like adding setting of text mode at beginning, to "clear screen" plus verify you are in expected mode:

```
begin:
    mov     ax,3        ; ah = 0 (set gfx mode), al = 3
    int     10h         ; set VGA text mode 80x25 chars
```

Compile + run + verify it works.

Then you can add 16 row loop to show all 256 symbols:

```
    ...
    xor     dl,dl   ; symbol value = 0
rows_loop:
    mov     cx,16   ; loop counter
    ...
```

and

```
    ...
    ; both dl and di are ready for next line
    ; so all is needed is just to loop until dl==0
    test    dl,dl   ; until all 256 symbols were displayed
    jnz     rows_loop
    ; exit back to DOS
    ...
```

... again run + verify it works ... then you can add the hexadecimal displaying. As you know you will do only 0-255 values, you can avoid the push/pop/looping completely, and just do the straightforward two digit translation:

```
    ...
    mov     es:[di+2],ax    ; write space after it

    ; show hexadecimal value of symbol - first digit
    mov     al,dl
    shr     al,4    ; al = upper 4 bits of dl (first hex digit)
    add     al,'0'
    cmp     al,'9'
    jbe     first_hex_digit_ok
    add     al,('A'-'0'-10) ; adjust it to A-F letter if needed
first_hex_digit_ok:
    mov     es:[di+4],ax    ; write first hex digit
    ; show hexadecimal value of symbol - second digit
    mov     al,dl
    and     al,0Fh  ; al = lower 4 bits of dl (second hex digit)
    add     al,'0'
    cmp     al,'9'
    jbe     second_hex_digit_ok
    add     al,('A'-'0'-10) ; adjust it to A-F letter if needed
second_hex_digit_ok:
    mov     es:[di+6],ax    ; write second hex digit
    ; write space after that
    mov     al,' '
    mov     es:[di+8],ax    ; write space after it

    ; advance loop for next symbol
    inc     dl
    ...
```

Debug + verify it works (I actually didn't so I just hope my code works).

Then you can take a look on the resulting code, and you may notice all the writes are like doing consecutive `es:[di] = word value`, so you can use `stosw` instead to get rid of the `di+?` displacement and `add di,5*2`, like optimized code after first try (plus I added modified colour for hex value):

```
    ...
; display 16 symbols (single row) on proper positions
    mov     di,TABLE_LEFT_TOP_OFFSET ; di = starting VRAM adr
    xor     dl,dl   ; symbol value = 0
rows_loop:
    mov     cx,16   ; loop counter
row_loop:
    ; show symbol + space
    mov     al,dl   ; symbol ASCII
    mov     ah,4h   ; colour attribute for symbol
    stosw           ; write symbol
    mov     al,' '
    stosw           ; write space after it
    ; show hexadecimal value of symbol - first digit
    mov     ah,2h   ; colour attribute for hex value
    mov     al,dl
    shr     al,4    ; al = upper 4 bits of dl (first hex digit)
    add     al,'0'
    cmp     al,'9'
    jbe     first_hex_digit_ok
    add     al,('A'-'0'-10) ; adjust it to A-F letter if needed
first_hex_digit_ok:
    stosw           ; write first hex digit
    ; show hexadecimal value of symbol - second digit
    mov     al,dl
    and     al,0Fh  ; al = lower 4 bits of dl (second hex digit)
    add     al,'0'
    cmp     al,'9'
    jbe     second_hex_digit_ok
    add     al,('A'-'0'-10) ; adjust it to A-F letter if needed
second_hex_digit_ok:
    stosw           ; write second hex digit
    ; write space after that
    mov     al,' '
    stosw           ; write space after it
    ; advance loop for next symbol
    inc     dl
    dec     cx
    jnz     row_loop
    ; both dl and di are ready for next line
    ; so all is needed is just to loop until dl==0
    test    dl,dl   ; until all 256 symbols were displayed
    jnz     rows_loop
    ...
```

And finally you may notice the row and rows loop doesn't do anything special over the end-of-row situation (because single row fills up full 80 chars of line, so it "automagically" advances to next line), so you can get rid of `cx` counter completely and just do single 256 symbols loop:

```
    ...
    xor     dl,dl   ; symbol value = 0
symbol_loop:
    ; show symbol + space
    ...

    ...
    stosw           ; write space after it
    ; advance loop for next symbol
    inc     dl
    jnz     symbol_loop ; until all 256 symbols are displayed
    ; exit back to DOS
    ...
```

And that's it. I didn't verify my code, so in case of some bug I'm sorry, but I'm trying you to present my way of thinking when writing asm code... actually that step doing hexa digits was kind of too big, I would probably do only first digit first, verify the `+'0'` `+'A'-'0'-10` works as expected, then I would add the second digit. Also as I had quite clear vision how the code will end in the final version ahead (due to my x86 asm experience), many of my register usage choices like `es:di` for writing offset, etc.. may look extraordinarily lucky, leading to simpler code later "for free". If you are new to x86 assembly, expect to find much better ideas after your initial version of code, and don't hesitate to overwrite more of it, just keep the development steps small enough to debug+verify only few changes at one time.

---

With your current code you would hit another problem:

```
    mov byte ptr es:[di+2],s[0]
```

There's no `mov mem, mem` variant of `mov` on x86 CPU, one side has to be register or immediate.

You would have to split that into two `mov`s, like using `AL` register to temporarily hold the value:

```
    mov al,s[0]
    mov es:[di+2],al
```

Keep using the instruction reference guide like http://x86.renejeschke.de/ to verify your source is targetting some existing variant of instruction, and that you fully understand how the instruction operates (especially with `mul/imul` and `div/idiv` instructions, as those are not working in common sense, producing many questions on stack overflow, which can be easily avoided by simply checking the reference guide first).

Comment: @xhfx you're welcome. You may consider accepting the answer in case it answers your question well, that works as "thank you" too (on stackoverflow site). Plus it helps other people when they're checking unanswered questions.

Comment: You are so kind! I am new to assembly language so come across many questions but I will try my best to make it with your recommended site as well as Google!